# Css not working after Magento 2 installation on AWS

Tags: magento2, css, static-content, aws, static-content-deploy

I've installed Magento 2 on AWS, however, the admin page is appearing like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: we can get the better idea if you could forward the console log error and which server you are using (apache/nginx) ?

Comment: apache. where can I get this log error?

Comment: in browser press F12 key, I have doubt you have deleted the .htaccess file of `pub/static`, you can place this file inside `pub/static' https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/pub/.htaccess

Comment: I've checked the .htaccess file on pub/static and it's there

Answer (score 1):

Open /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Find `<Directory /var/www/html>`

Replace rules inside with below rules.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart server and you are done.

Comment: This had worked for me.

Comment: hi, I've already tried this and it's still the same

Comment: What is the path of your magento 2 directory?

Comment: /var/www/html/magento2

Comment: I have updated a answer. please check and do change there.

Comment: it's still the same :(

Comment: which file are you editing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70676/discussion-between-meetanshi-and-cmsantos).

Answer (score 0):

dependent on your languages you are working with redeploy

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US
```

just to add some meat to this answer

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: hi, I've already tried this and it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps for resolve issue.

```
1)php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2)php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (add language en_GB if your default language is not englishg)
3)chmod -R 755 pub;chmod -R 755 var; (set permission)
```

Comment: hi, I've already tried this and it's still the same

Comment: check pub/static folder have any htaccess file ? if not then please add htaccess file form default magento setup , may be issue due to missing htaccess file

Comment: can I copy the .htaccess file from root to this folder?

Comment: I've copied the file and it's still the same

Comment: no , please download fresh magento and then copy pub/static/ htaccess file

Comment: what is your magento version ?

Comment: my version is 2.2.1 ce

Comment: I've copied .htaccess file from a fresh magento and it's still the same :/

Comment: ohh............ :(

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps and i am sure it will work:

1) Open .htacess, find and comment Options FollowSymLinks e.g #Options +FollowSymLinks

2) Deploy content by using the command: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

3) Set permissions : chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static pub/media